# Android Fragment manager incompatible types

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i get this error in my main activity when trying to set up manager to do fragment transactions. error:

**Incompatiple types,**

**Required: Android.Support.v4.app.FragmentManager.**

**Found: Android.app.FragmentManager**

on this line:

```
FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
```

**Full Code for main activity:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment,
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

private FrontFragment mFrontFragment;

private CharSequence mTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    mFrontFragment = (FrontFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.front_fragment);

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    FrontFragment frontFragment = new FrontFragment();

    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);

            FragmentTransaction transaction =manager.beginTransaction();
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change this line:

```
FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
```

to this:

```
 FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: this work but now my FragmentTransaction transaction =manager.beginTransaction(); can't resovle manager.

Comment: It's because you `manager` variable is declared inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: yes, of course, sorry about that. i just started working with fragments and is really confused, now, one last question. Is it okay using this line of code: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction(); looks weird to me

Comment: You can just shorten it to `FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction()` provided that you are importing android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.  Just hover your mouse over FragmentTransaction to make sure it is referring to the v4 support version.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *getSupportFragmentManager()* instead of *getFragmentManager() ;-)

Comment: You have to use only one set of classes - either from v4 support package or the from andoroid app :-). Im not sure, but I would suggest to try to import   _android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction_ instead of _android.app.FragmentTransaction_