# Android Fragments Get Issue With getFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add a fragment into relative layout and here's my MainActivity.java :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        FragmentOne f1 = new FragmentOne();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f1);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

when I run that code, I got this error :

`Error:(15, 61) error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

how to add fragment into relative layout? I tried to change `getFragmentManager();` into `getSupportFragmentManager();`

also didn't work. any idea what's wrong with this?

UPDATE : here's what I got when I change `getFragmentManager();` into `getSupportFragmentManager();`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Fragment manager incompatible types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723749/android-fragment-manager-incompatible-types)

Comment: Look at the call stack - your activity doesn't implement an interface your fragment expects. See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports. You're importing `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`, so the variable `FragmentManager fragmentManager` is of type `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` but `getFragmentManager` returns the platform version of fragment manager `android.app.FragmentManager`, so these are incompatible types.

Since you are using `AppCompatActivity`, you should be using `getSupportFragmentManager`.

You say

> I tried to change getFragmentManager(); into getSupportFragmentManager(); also didn't work.

What does "also didn't work" mean? That should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer. please check my update above. that's what I saw on my phone.